# Making sense of God's different actions of the creation

Tags: parashat-bereishit, creation

I'm trying to categorize different actions God takes in the process of creation as appears in [Genesis.1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

```
   Part of creation     | Said? | Then       | Then      | Then
1. Heaven and Earth:    | No    | Bara       |  -        | -
2. Light:               | Yes   | it was so  | named     | -
3. Firmament:           | Yes   | Asah       | it was so | named
4. Gathering of waters: | Yes   | it was so  | named     | - 
5. Fauna:               | Yes   | it was so  | Earth did | -
6. Luminaries:          | Yes   | it was so  | Asah      | set in place
7. Fish and birds:      | Yes   | Barah      | blessed   | -
8. Land animals:        | Yes   | Asah       | -         | -
9. Man:                 | Yes   | Barah      | blessed   | -
```

(in Genesis.2 we can see some additional Chidushim regarding Man (he's now Yatzar-ed), and animals (same).

As I can see, each part of the creation was made in a different way/pattern (#2 and #4 are actually same), some parts are said into creation and the first isn't, some are done first and then "it was so" and some "it was so" and then done, some are Barah-ed and some Asah-ed, some are named and some aren't, etc.

Do our sources address this inconsistency?

NB: This question is **general**, about general inconsistency in the process of the creation as described in Genesis, not about specific excuses about every part.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17407/why-name-but-five-creations

Comment: I don't know why you assume there has to be one general answer. Rashi and others address these questions one by one.

Comment: @N.T. I don't, I assume there should be a pattern, a logic. Discrete interpretation, as you mentioned, seems a huge problem to me as a failure to see a big picture, to see unified divine thought.

Comment: I think discrete interpretation and big picture are two sides of the same coin. You have to use both, but discrete interpretation comes first.